# sql, getting parents and child from one table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a simple sql statement to select a parent and dependents from one table based on the parents hiring date. Because the hiring date field in dependents row is null, I'm only getting the parents. Can someone help?

```
PRIM KEY    RECORD  LAST FIRST HIRE DATE 
12345   1   JONES   MARY    1/1/2017 
12345   2   JONES   TIM 
6789    1   SMITH   CAROL   5/12/2014 
23456   1   WHITAKE REGINA  5/14/2017 
23456   2   WHITAKE JOE
```

parent has a row for each child in the table. Parent is 1 and all dependents have a 2. They share a primary key (parent's ssn). I want to select all parents who was hired between specific date range and their dependants rows. The dependent hire date column is null. So when I write the following... I'm only getting the parent rows...

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, RECORD_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, HIRE_DATE
FROM CIGNA_ELIGIBILITY
WHERE(HIRE_DATE BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171131');
```

Comment: PRIM KEY RECORD LAST  FIRST  HIRE DATE
12345 1 JONES MARY 1/1/2017
12345 2 JONES TIM 
6789 1 SMITH CAROL 5/12/2014
23456 1 WHITAKE REGINA 5/14/2017
23456 2 WHITAKE JOE

Comment: parent has a row for each child in the table. Parent is 1 and all dependents have a 2. They share a primary key (parent's ssn). I want to select all parents who was hired between specific date range and their dependants rows. The dependent hire date column is null. So when I write the following... I'm only getting the parent rows... 
               SELECT 
               PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, RECORD_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, HIRE_DATE


               FROM CIGNA_ELIGIBILITY
                WHERE (HIRE_DATE BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171131')
                
               ")

Comment: @SHELL: How are you maintaining `parent-child` relationship?

Comment: a primary key,,,PRIM KEY RECORD LAST  FIRST  HIRE DATE
12345 1 JONES MARY 1/1/2017
12345 2 JONES TIM 
6789 1 SMITH CAROL 5/12/2014
23456 1 WHITAKE REGINA 5/14/2017
23456 2 WHITAKE JOE

Comment: Do **not** post code or additional information as comments. [edit] your question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, that on the date range provided, you want to return records associated with it and all dependents(provided that parents/childs has same `prim_key`) then one way could be to use `IN`.

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where t1.prim_key in
(
select t2.prim_key
from table1 t2
where t2.hire_date between '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-30'
);
```

what the above query does is that from sub-query select `PRIM_KEY` of the date range specified and then in main query select all record associated with it.

**Result:**

```
+---+----------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   | prim_key | record | last  | first |      hire_date      |
+---+----------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| 1 |    12345 |      1 | JONES | MARY  | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |
| 2 |    12345 |      2 | JONES | TIM   | NULL                |
+---+----------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YFM49156)**

---

**Update:**

Another option could be to use `exists`:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where exists
(
select 1
from table1 t2
where t1.prim_key = t2.prim_key
and t2.hire_date between '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-30'
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help but I run the code and no data is coming back.

Comment: Kindly check attached DEMO. Its works like a charm  :-)

Comment: Thanks Zarruq, In your second option, did you mean to put the '1' by the subquery select?

Comment: @SHELL: Yes, you can use `*` or `1`. Also kindly read about [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :-)